# Bootstrap template with iframe and footer combined

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, iframe

my site has a standard header, content, and footer area. what i am trying to accomplish is make my iframe height 100% of its container however, the problem i am running into is the css needed for bootstrap sticky footer to work.

any ideas would be great!

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ex0Loy0t/)

```
 <div id="wrap">
    <div id="content">
      <iframe src="https://jsfiddle.net/" height="100%" width="100%" style="height:100%;width:100%;">    
      </iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="push">   
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer id="footer">my footer</footer>

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

#content {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
    margin: 0 auto -60px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#push,
#footer {
    height: 60px;
}
#footer .container {
    border-top: 1px solid #dededd;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you properly, give this a try.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ex0Loy0t/2/

HTML:

```
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="content">
      <iframe src="https://jsfiddle.net/" height="100%" width="100%" style="height:100%;width:100%;">    
      </iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="push">   
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer id="footer">my footer</footer>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

#content {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
    min-height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
    margin: 0 auto 60px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#push,
#footer {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
#footer .container {
    border-top: 1px solid #dededd;
}
```

Comment: i got the css straight from bootstrap. it seems without the auto if the user makes the screen height smaller the footer overlaps the main content.

Comment: @Marco I've made a slight change to my answer for the #wrap CSS - give that a try.